# Protocol Design robustness against corruption

Tags: design, protocol

I am currently in the design phase of a binary protocol which is intended to be agnostic of the transport layer, meaning it should work on top of for example websockets as well as serial device to device communication.

In short each participant maintains and send and a receive buffer of size X. Received messages are put into the receive buffer, send messages a placed into the send buffer before being "flushed" into the transport layer, either time based or event based.

The protocol so far looks something like this:

```
message[0] = 'G' //static identifier common to all messages
message[1] + message[2] //message type a command id if you will
message[3] // payload length
message[4] .. message[payload_length-1] // payload
message[payload_length - 1] // CRC32 of the entire message
```

My question is if there is any technique to detect malformed message and resolve it without damaging any other proper messages in the receive buffer. The challenge here is that I may not receive one packet within one message as the support for a chunked transfer is needed.

I think that the only way to really enfore buffer integrity is to check for a incoming message:

- Did we receive a header 'G' prior to this message

  - if not discard the message
  - if yes read until the suggested payload length ends and perform the CRC check. if it fails discard the message

But this is already an issue. If the payload of a message that we received prior happened to contain a 'G' that means that we potential discarded part of the next message. This image should illustrate the problem:
[image: issue]

Comment: Is there a reason you can't encode the payload such that it can't contain the static identified sequence? Ie some sort of escaping system.

Comment: I do not understand the problem. How could you possible "damage" a message if all you do is read bytes from a buffer?

Comment: There are an effectively infinite number of such techniques. Which are appropriate for your situation depends on a vast range of factors, including but not limited to: 1) what error rate are you prepared to tolerate (must be >0)? 2) Do you want to detect or correct errors? 3) What are the likely failure modes of your transmission medium (flipped bits, missing bits, etc)? 4) Do you need to protect against malicious attacks as well as random errors? 5) How much overhead are you prepared to accept to implement this scheme? etc etc etc

Comment: @MartinMaat In a naive scheme if you misinterpret one message, then that can causes you to misinterpret all future messages. For example, if the length of a message is corrupted, then future messages will be misinterpreted because the wrong bytes are read for their length as well. Effectively the OP is asking for a [self-synchronizing code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-synchronizing_code).

Comment: @PhilipKendall  I see, one message's corruption can get you out of sync and inhibit you from finding the next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that creating such a transport-agnostic protocol makes sense because different transports provide drastically different guarantees. A protocol that sits on top of the application-layer WebSockets (OSI layer 7) will have different concerns than a protocol on top of UDP (OSI layer 4) or on top of the physical layer (OSI layer 1).

Instead of creating one protocol that could work on top of everything, assemble a suitable protocol stack instead.

Many of the challenges you are trying to solve have existing solution.
For example, the Ethernet protocol (OSI layer 2) also has to find the start of the message in a stream. Each Ethernet packet starts with an Ethernet preamble or syncword, 56 bits of alternating 1s and 0s. Aside from marking the start of a packet, this allows the sender and receiver to synchronize their clocks, and possibly also allows the receiver to awaken from a low-power state.

WebSockets already deals with framed messages instead of streams so that no syncword is necessary or helpful. Or viewed another way, WebSockets already provides the necessary frame headers (on top of the TCP stream) so that you don't have to add them.

If you are building on top of a lower-level stream protocol and want the ability to search ahead in the stream to find the next message, the message must not contain the syncword. Therefore, you must encode the actual contents so that the syncword cannot be contained. Two general approaches:

- You define an escaping mechanism. Let's say you want to escape `G` (`0x47`). We define `\` (`0x5c`) to be the escape character. We define the escape sequences `\ \` for the escape code, and `\ 1` for `G`, with all other `\ .` sequences being illegal. A stream `. . \ . G .` might then be encoded as `. . \ \ . \ 1 .`

  There are various ways to improve efficiency of this scheme, for example only requiring the escape marker to be escaped for valid escapes. Then, `\ . \ \ . \ 1 . \ G` might be escaped as `\ . \ \ \ . \ \ 1 . \ \ \ 1`
- You encode each *n*-sized input block into an *m*-sized output block, with *n* < *m*. Your encoding prevents illegal output bit patterns from occurring. The larger your blocks are, the more efficient (*n*/*m*) your encoding can become.

  For example, Base64 is such an encoding that represents arbitrary 8-bit input into a 6-bit ASCII-safe subset. The input is converted in 24-bit blocks (three octets), producing four ASCII characters. As these are represented as octets, the scheme achieves a 3/4 (75%) efficiency. Much higher efficiencies are possible for larger block sizes and when there are fewer illegal output patterns.

  Aside of preventing illegal patterns, encodings are also used for error detection and correction, e.g. the Hamming codes.

  Encodings or scramblings are also commonly used on the physical layer (OSI layer 1) since it is undesirable for electrical signals to stay level for long durations, e.g. long sequences of zeros.
- Actually, escaping and block encoding aren't opposites. Variable-length codes (such as Huffman codings) can produce shorter output messages when the data distribution is known. Escaping is an example of a variable length code where all input units are mapped to themselves, except for the escaped characters that are mapped to multi-unit sequences.

However, the ability to *search*  for the next message start is not needed if the underlying protocol already frames messages (e.g. WebSockets) or if the message header contains the message size and the header was communicated reliably (e.g. TCP).

Similarly, the lower protocol layers might make it unnecessary to guard against corruption yourself. TCP and WebSockets already provide guarantees about the integrity of the data (integrity in the reliability sense, not necessarily in the security sense). If you are concerned about lower-level issues, consider whether you want to guard against random bit flips or against against larger changes, e.g. dropped parts. To protect against random bit flips, consider Hamming codes, but note that there's a tradeoff between block size, encoding efficiency, and error detection capabilities.

Comment: This was on point, thank you not only for making me think about that this is a solved problem depending on the transport layer, as well as giving a nice explanation on the different measures.

Answer (score 2):

I recently developed something similar and I do not feel I have the same problem.

The first thing I assess as inconvenient is that you have domain knowledge in your transport layer. That is the Gxx. The packet separator should not see or rely on that kind of information. It is application specific.

So your packet markers should be outside that space. I serialize messages that have all the information there is to know about the message on the application level in them. The result is just a byte array. This is what you want to get across.

Then I use a packet head of a couple of bytes long, comparable to your G. You want this to be a bit longer than one byte though to minimize the chance of interpreting regular data as a head.

The next thing could be the length value (for the payload = serialized message), then the serialized message and finally a tail. The tail is a constant series of bytes like the head. If you are really paranoid you could maintain your CRC32 in between the serialized message and the tail.

Now, if you find a head, read the length of the payload, read the payload, read the tail and it checks out (is indeed a tail), AND your serialized message can be deserialized OK, chances are you have a good message and everything is fine. If not, discard it and start looking for the first head one byte further than the head that did not have a good message behind it.

One final neat trick: if you want to be able to send bursts of messages (to be sent in one session) you can use and end marker. If the first thing after a tail is an end, the receiver will know it just got "the last carriage in the train" and won't wait for more.